# Pass variable from jenkins to testng.xml

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, testng

I want to run test cases depending on variables passed from jenkins 
for example, choose testcases you want to run :
testcaseOne, testcaseTwo

in pom.xml (maven) :

```
    <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                    <configuration>

                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>

                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <chooseCase>${chooseCase}</chooseCase>   <--this dont work
                        </systemPropertyVariables>

                        <parallel>tests</parallel>
                        <threadCount>10</threadCount>

                    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I have two testng @test methods:

```
@Test(groups="caseOne")
@Test(groups="caseTwo")
```

And my testng.xml file:

```
<test name="Test">
    <groups>
    <run>
      <include name="${chooseCase}"/>
    </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
      <class name="AppTest"/>
      <class name="AppTest2"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
```

How to pass this parameter depending on what and how many tests i want to run ?
Maybe there is totally different way to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use BeanShell script in your testng.xml file http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#beanshell and read system variables in it, something like:

```
<test name="Test">
    <method-selectors>
        <method-selector>
            <script language="beanshell">
                <![CDATA[
                    String myTestGroup = System.getProperty("chooseCase");
                    groups.containsKey(myTestGroup);
                ]]>
            </script>
        </method-selector>
    </method-selectors>

    <classes>
        <class name="AppTest"/>
        <class name="AppTest2"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

Comment: You are the best. Thanks!

How about if i would like to make it multiple choice ? Can I pass those variables in loop ? Lets say I chosed testCaseOne and testCaseTwo in the same time ? But should work with only one choise aswell , so if i add second method selector, it will be empty sometimes (if I choose only one option)

Comment: BeanShell is 'basically' Java (http://www.beanshell.org/docs.html) so you can have multiple system properties or one string with comma separated values and then split it into array and use for loop. You can even have methods in `<script language="beanshell">` only condition is to return true or false at the end (as is written in TestNG doc). There is no need for multiple `<method-selector>` in this case you can handle everything in one script.

Comment: how to handle it in one script ? can you give some example ?
I cant find any cases of use multiple parameters

Comment: Lets say my `String myTestGroup = System.getProperty("chooseCase");` returns `caseOne,caseTwo` how to access second parameter ?

Comment: As I said, it's basically Java, so something like `String myTestGroup = "caseOne,caseTwo";
        String[] splited = myTestGroup.split(",");
        for (String s : splited) {
            // ...
        }` should works.

Comment: `<method-selector>
            <script language="beanshell">
                <![CDATA[
                   
                     String myTestGroup = "caseOne,caseTwo"; 
      String[] splited = myTestGroup.split(","); 
      for (String s : splited) { 
      groups.containsKey(s);
      }
                    
                ]]>
            </script>
        </method-selector>`  this loop works just fine in java, but in tesng.xml it doesnt run any tests

Comment: looks like beanshell gives only one param: `groups.containsKey(splited[0]);
      groups.containsKey(splited[1]);` will run only first method `splited[0]` , second one is ignored

Comment: In case you have more complicated code you have to add `return` statement(s) explicitly. So `for (String s : splited) {
                            if(groups.containsKey(s)) {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                        
                        return false;` works fine for me.